# PHP : not return to sender page after clicking a button to print

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that shows some search results.
At the end I put a form with a button to print the content of this page.

With microsoft Edge (not tested with internet explorer), after the printing (or cancel printing) this page is shown again and I can refine results and print them again etc.
With Chrome, after clicking the print button and before the printing form show up, the sender page changes to the site's home page.
Why?

How can I force the page to stay, please?
Below is the code I use

```
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function printW() {
    window.print();
    window.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<form name="footerForm" id="footerForm" >
    <div class="example-screen">
        <table style="background-color:rgb(252,252,252)">           
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="printW();" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button"><img src="http://......./Print.png" alt=""/>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the onclick event:

```
<button onclick="printW(); return false" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button"><img src="http://......./Print.png" alt=""/>
```

The "return false" is inserted to stop the default action, which is to follow the link.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print the page, there is no need to reload the page with following command:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Also you don't need to put the button inside form to print the page. Because of form, it gets submitted on click of a button. You can just put it without form like this,

```
<div class="example-screen">
    <table style="background-color:rgb(252,252,252)">           
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button onclick="printW();" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button">
                    <img src="http://......./Print.png" alt=""/>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically, this is better answer. Why to add a form and then use `return false` to stop execution.